# A change to a field isn't being retained when using BinaryFormatter - why?

Tags: c#

I have two methods. One method will cause SignInStatus = true and other false. For some reason when I add in the binary writers and readers the SignInStatus is always false. I have a binary reader and writer method:

```
public static void WriteEmployeeDataBase()
{

    FileStream filestreams = new FileStream(Convert.ToString(Settings.Default["Path"]) + "\\EmployeeDatabase.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.ReadWrite);
   formatter.Serialize(filestreams, Employee.EmployeeDatabase);

}

public static void ReadEmployeeDataBase()
{

    FileStream filestream = new FileStream(Convert.ToString(Settings.Default["Path"]) + "\\EmployeeDatabase.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    Employee.EmployeeDatabase = (List<Employee>)formatter.Deserialize(filestream);

    ...
```

Then I have two methods SignIn and Signout

```
public bool SignIn()
{
    ReadEmployeeDataBase();

    if (this.SignInStatus == false)
    {

        this.SignInStatus = true;     
        WriteEmployeeDataBase();
    }

    ...
}

public bool SignOut()
{

    ReadEmployeeDataBase();

    if (this.SignInStatus == true )
    {


        this.SignInStatus = false;
        WriteEmployeeDataBase();
    }
}
```

Here is my class

```
[Serializable]   
class Employee 
{
    public bool SignInStatus { get; set; }  

    public static BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter()

    List<Class> mylist = new List<Class>;

    public Employee() { ... }

    ...
}
```

Here is how I create the object:

```
public static CreateObject(string name)    
{

    mylist.Add(new Object(name));

    ...
```

Comment: If it is always false, I am assuming it is not deserializing the SignInStatus

When I use reflection we put attributes on the members we need to serialize,

Comment: IE [DataMember]
I'm not sure if this is what is missing here... but it code me

Comment: strong advice: **do not use `BinaryFormatter` for persistance** - it is likely to bite you *hard* - it bites *lots* of people hard. I strongly recommend *just about any other serializer instead*. I'd be happy to make recommendations.

Comment: @IlanKeshet `[DataMember]` is for `DataContractSerializer`, not `BinaryFormatter`

Comment: @Marc Gravell I used Newton Json.net and I had the exact same problem.

Comment: @JennyLee are you sure this isn't simply a file location / copy issue? Using something like json.net (which you mention) it would be trivial to see what the file contents are at each point. Note: re-writing a "database" file each time you make a change is **horrendous** for performance, so I hope this doesn't need more than a couple of users.

Comment: How should I do it then?

Comment: We use a custom binary deserializer that uses those attributes ... So I wasn't sure ;)

Comment: I need more coffee :)

Comment: What do i do? Please help!

Comment: @JennyLee if by "how should I do it then?" you mean the database itself: see *just about any actual database system*, which can include standalone files but more commonly means an out-of-process server. For a very low load, manual file updates *can* work, but... it is the nuclear option. I'm trying to look at the code, but it isn't obvious what the problem is. Looking.

Comment: @JennyLee it also looks like you're using a `static List<T>` as your main data - that is almost always a *really bad idea*. Is this perhaps a website?

Comment: @Marc Gravell I should mention that I am creating the objects and saving them like this 

public static CreateObject(string name)
{
   List<Class> mylist = new List<Class>
mylist.Add(new Object(name));
}

Comment: @JennyLee that line doesn't show what `mylist` is - it seems to be a new list every time `CreateObject` is used, so : it won't actually be meaningful to add to that list if you're just going to drop it on the floor

Comment: Yes I am using a Static List<class> as my main datasource. What is the better way?

Comment: the new list is placed in the class field

Comment: @JennyLee that is a really complex question to which there is no simple short answer; "not doing that" is the short version. If this is a concurrent system (such as a website) it is **absolutely guaranteed** to scew up horribly if you use something like a static list. You can *just about* get away with that type of design for a single user app - typically a desktop app. So: what is your system? desktop? or concurrent (such as website)?

Comment: It is just a simple desktop Timeclock that marks what time you signned in and signned out and some more things.

Comment: @JennyLee single user? in that case it might *just about* work, but it ... well, it isn't anything like how you'd ever write a "real" system.

Comment: Yes just one desktop.

Comment: are you perhaps swallowing exceptions? you aren't actually closing your files (and you're missing the `using` statements that would do it for you) - which means you could be getting errors due to being unable to open a file that is already open. So: any large `catch` blocks that are swallowing the real problem?

Comment: I dont have any.

Comment: @JennyLee here's a minimal example that shows something *like* your code working - successfully reading and writing the file, and showing updates: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/4c10cb89973302b25bbb513eeec86197 ; without your *actual* code that shows the problem happening, it is hard to speculate more. Plus... I need to sleep now :)

Comment: I ended up deleting every single ReadEmployeeDataBase() and @Marc Gravell WriteEmployeeDataBase()  in my program and trying to rewrite it. But I just dont understand the mistake I'm doing. I am still going to use these methods but seems like I place them in the wrong place and suddenly my program stops function.